# Reduce size of sample with very high data content

Tags: sample-size, down-sample

I am analysing cells at 10 different timepoints (T0-T9).

```
time      T0    T1    T2    T3   T4     T5    T6    T7     T8    T9 
cells     298   154   400   551  1066   453   751   1156   982   13617
```

Is there a statistically correct way to downsample T9, so that cells from this timepoint will not "overshadow" the remaining cells?

Until now I have manually downsampled T9 to 1500.

Comment: Why do you think it is necessary to throw away data?

Comment: When plotting the cells (2 dim) for visual data analysis, the cells at T9 overshadow the result.